# How to get value of another property with Joi?

Tags: javascript, joi

How can I define property of resulting value if I have optional schema property like:

```
passport: customJoi.string().optional().strip(true),
passportSeries: ? // return passport ? passport.slice(0,4) : undefined,
```

I tried to use when and custom but it seems that they work only if passportSeries in original object are defined and it looks like I don't have access to passport property anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of the [`ref` method](https://joi.dev/api/?v=17.9.1#refkey-options) in `joi`, which allows you to refers to another field in the object:

```js
Joi.object({
  passport: Joi.string().optional().strip(true),
  passportSeries: Joi.ref('passport', {
    adjust: (val) => val.slice(0, 4),
  }),
});
```

By default, `Joi.ref('field')` refers to the exact value of the field, which is usually helpful for cases like `password` and `confirm_password`. However, you can make use of the second argument `options.adjust` that allows you to adjust the value before matching.

---

However, I think the question is a bit ambiguous here. If your purpose is to create another property based on an existing property, you can make use of [`forbidden` method](https://joi.dev/api/?v=17.9.1#anyforbidden) and [`default` method](https://joi.dev/api/?v=17.9.1#anydefaultvalue) instead:

```js
Joi.object({
  passport: Joi.string().optional().strip(true),
  passportSeries: Joi.forbidden().default(
    Joi.ref('passport', { adjust: (val) => val.slice(0, 4) })
  ),
});
```

Basically, you mark the property `passportSeries` as `forbidden()`, which means this key cannot exists in your original object. However, with the use of `default()` you can set a value based on another value with the help of `ref()` method.